# Access function of component wrapped with HOC in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a HOC called `withBackgroundAndAnimation` that renders a components background (Users can set a video or image as background) since it is something that repeats itself often.

For this question, take a look at the relevant 3 components:

`ViewManager` - my top-level component that manages what tab is actually active.

|

`withBackgroundAndAnimation` - HOC that enhanced Components by giving them the correct background.

|

`PinlockComponent` - A component that is presented when the app initializes and the user has to enter a 4-digit pin.

So as you can imagine, I am using `withBackgroundAndAnimation` to enhance the `PinlockComponent`.

**This is where I am having trouble:**

When the user correctly inputs the 4 digit pin the `onCorrectPin` prop-method would have been called and the `ViewManager` would have removed the `PinlockComponent`. Now I have the HOC in the way and can't seem to access the WrappedComponents method callback.

How can I achieve this?

**Code**

```
export const withBackgroundAndMountingAnimation = WrappedComponent => {
  class WrapperComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        opacityValue: new Animated.Value(0),
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      return Animated.timing(
        this.state.opacityValue, 
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 300,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          isInteraction: false,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }
      ).start();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      return Animated.timing(
        this.state.opacityValue, 
        {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 100,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          isInteraction: false,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }
      ).start();
    }

    ...

    render() {
      const { settings } = this.props
      const { backgroundOpacity } = this.props.settings.layoutCategory

      if (settings.backgroundCategory.isBackgroundUsingVideo && !Video) {
        Video = require('react-native-video').default
      } else if (!FastImage) {
        FastImage = require('react-native-fast-image').default
      }

      return (
        <View style={styles.flex1}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.flex1, { opacity: this.state.opacityValue }]}>
            {this.renderVideo()}

            <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      settings: state.settings,
    };
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(WrapperComponent);
}
```

Comment: Which is the method callback you are taking about and how do you access it? Do you face difficult calling `onCorrectPin` method from prop in `PinlockComponent`

Comment: "__the ViewManager would have removed the PinlockComponent__" ?

How so?

Comment: @UtsavPatel by conditionally rendering the PinlockComponent if onCorrectPin was entered successful or not.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That is correct!

Comment: @WalterMonecke Please elabore on it a bit. You not not receive the props. How do you render the WrappedComponent. Are you using refs? Do you see any error. As of now there is very little information to work with

Comment: Please update question with more context of the wrapped component code/logic and the what/how of rendering the returned component decorated by `withBackgroundAndMountingAnimation`.

Comment: @WalterMonecke Please update your post with more information

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue would be with your `ViewManager` and not your HOC. Based on the comments I assume your `ViewManager` should look something like:

```
const ViewManager = () => {
    const [locked, setLocked] = useState(true);
    const WrappedPinlock = withBackgroundAndMountingAnimation(PinlockComponent);

    return (
        <div>
            {locked && <WrappedPinlock onCorrectPin={() => setLocked(false)} />
            {!locked && <YourApp />}
        </div>
    )
};
```